# why in the main loop ('running' in this code) is not responding after clicking the 'start' button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a basic game. I have mainly two codes for :(i) Menu (ii) Basic Game. I want to run 'while game_over' loop after clicking 'start' button. But the code does not respond after I click 'start' button.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
pygame.init()
w=800
h=600
yellow=(255,255,0)
player_size=25
player_pos=[w/2,h-(2*player_size)]
enemy_size=25
enemy_pos=[random.randint(0,w-enemy_size),0]
enemy_list=[ ]
Menu_bg_color=(34,139,34)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,125)
bright_blue=(0,0,255)
font_size=35
b1_pos=[w/2-50,h/2]
b1_size=[105,50]
bg_color=(0,0,0)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
speed=10
score=0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
myFont=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",font_size)
Menu_myFont=pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.tff",font_size)
running=True
Menu_running=True

#GAME CODE
def GameCode():
    global game_over
    global score
    global speed
    global player_pos
    def set_level(score,speed):
        if score<10:
            speed=5
        elif score<20:
            speed=6
        elif score<30:
            speed=8
        elif score<40:
            speed=10
        elif score<50:
            speed=13
        elif score<200:
            speed=15
        else:
            speed=20
        return speed
    def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
        delay=random.random()
        if len(enemy_list)<6 and delay<0.1:
            x_pos=random.randint(0,w-enemy_size)
            y_pos=0
            enemy_list.append([x_pos,y_pos])
    def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,     (enemy_pos[0],enemy_pos[1],enemy_size,enemy_size))
    def update_enemy_pos(enemy_list,score):
        for idx,enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
           if enemy_pos[1]>=0 and enemy_pos[1]<h:
            enemy_pos[1]+=speed
           else:
               enemy_list.pop(idx)
               score+=1
        return score
    def detect_collision(player_pos,enemy_pos):
        p_x=player_pos[0]
        p_y=player_pos[1]
        e_x=enemy_pos[0]
        e_y=enemy_pos[1]
        if (e_x>=p_x and e_x<(p_x+player_size)) or (p_x>=e_x and p_x<(e_x+enemy_size)):
            if (e_y>=p_y and e_y<(p_y+player_size)) or (p_y>=e_y and p_y<(e_y+enemy_size)):
                return True
        return False
    def collision_check(enemy_list,player_pos):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            if detect_collision(enemy_pos,player_pos):
                return True
        return False
    while game_over==False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                x=player_pos[0]
                y=player_pos[1]
                if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x-=player_size
                elif event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                    y-=player_size
                elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x+=player_size
                elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y+=player_size
                player_pos=[x,y]
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        #screen.blit(road,(0,0))
        drop_enemies(enemy_list)
        score=update_enemy_pos(enemy_list,score)
        speed=set_level(score,speed)
        text='Your Score is:' + str(score)
        label=myFont.render(text,1,yellow)
        screen.blit(label,(w/2,h-40))
        if collision_check(enemy_list,player_pos):
            game_over=True
            break
        draw_enemies(enemy_list)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(player_pos[0],player_pos[1],player_size,player_size))
        clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
#MENU CODE
def MenuCode():
    global game_over
    def button(b1_pos,b1_size):
        mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if (b1_pos[0]<mouse_pos[0]<(b1_pos[0]+b1_size[0])) and (b1_pos[1]<mouse_pos[1]<(b1_pos[1]+b1_size[1])):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,bright_blue,(b1_pos[0],b1_pos[1],b1_size[0],b1_size[1]))
            if click[0]==1:
                     game_over=False
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,(b1_pos[0],b1_pos[1],b1_size[0],b1_size[1]))
        text='START'
        label=Menu_myFont.render(text,1,red)
        screen.blit(label,(w/2-38,h/2+5))
        Menu_running=True
    while Menu_running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(Menu_bg_color)
        button(b1_pos,b1_size)
        #button(b1_pos,b1_size,'quit')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break;
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    if MenuCode():
            if game_over==False:
                    GameCode()
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: "freesansbold.tff" should be "freesansbold.ttf" (TrueType Font). You need to refer to "game_over" in the top level code, just referencing it with "global" within functions does not make it a global variable. Then try again...

Comment: Among other things, your `MenuCode()` function never returns anything, so the `if MenuCode():` is never true and `GameCode()` never gets called. The global `game_over` variable is never initialized.

Comment: @martineau what should be the changes? I am just a beginner so it would be helpful.

Comment: Supreme: I started trying to fix it, but after making some progress, gave up because I couldn't decipher the logic — largely due to your use of so many global flag variables coupled with nested function definitions and event-processing loops.

Comment: @martineau it's fine thanks for helping anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a substantially revised version of your code that doesn't have the problem. I have revised the code so it closely adheres to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines and also eliminated many of the global variables you had by making them local to the function that uses them.

One of the primary cosmetic things I did was determine which of the globals were unchanging constants and which were variables whose values actually changed. After doing that, I changed the names of the constant ones to all UPPERCASE (as per PEP 8) and moved those with varying values to inside whichever function was actually using them.

The most extensive changes were made to the menu handling function — now named `menu_code()` — which was probably the main source of your problems. To help facilitate the rewrite, I've added a `MenuButton` class to encapsulate their behavior to a large degree and reduce repetitious code.

Note that there may be problems with the `game_code()` function because because I didn't attempted to optimize, test, or debug it.

Hopefully this will provide you with a good base upon which to further develop the game. I strongly suggest you read and start following PEP 8.

```
import random
import pygame as pyg

W, H = 800, 600
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 125)
BRIGHT_BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PLAYER_SIZE = 25
ENEMY_SIZE = 25
FONT_SIZE = 35
BG_COLOR = BLACK
FPS = 30
START, QUIT = 0, 1  # Button selection codes returned by menu_code()

pyg.init()
screen = pyg.display.set_mode((W, H))
pyg.display.set_caption('Basic Game')
clock = pyg.time.Clock()
game_font = pyg.font.SysFont("monospace", FONT_SIZE)
menu_font = pyg.font.SysFont("freesansbold.ttf", FONT_SIZE)

def game_code():
    enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, W-ENEMY_SIZE), 0]
    enemy_list = []
    game_over = False
    player_pos = [W/2, H - 2*PLAYER_SIZE]
    score = 0
    speed = 10

    def get_speed(score):
        if score < 10:
            speed = 5
        elif score < 20:
            speed = 6
        elif score < 30:
            speed = 8
        elif score < 40:
            speed = 10
        elif score < 50:
            speed = 13
        elif score < 200:
            speed = 15
        else:
            speed = 20
        return speed

    def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
        delay = random.random()
        if len(enemy_list) < 6 and delay < 0.1:
            x_pos = random.randint(0, W-ENEMY_SIZE)
            y_pos = 0
            enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])

    def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            pyg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE,
                          (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], ENEMY_SIZE, ENEMY_SIZE))

    def update_enemy_pos(enemy_list, score):
        for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
            if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < H:
                enemy_pos[1] += speed
            else:
                enemy_list.pop(idx)
                score += 1
        return score

    def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
        p_x, p_y = player_pos
        e_x, e_y = enemy_pos
        if ((e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + PLAYER_SIZE))
            or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x + ENEMY_SIZE))):
            if ((e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y+PLAYER_SIZE))
                or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y + ENEMY_SIZE))):
                return True
        return False

    def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
                return True
        return False

    while not game_over:
        for event in pyg.event.get():
            if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
                game_over = True
                break
            if event.type == pyg.KEYDOWN:
                x = player_pos[0]
                y = player_pos[1]
                if event.key == pyg.K_LEFT:
                    x -= PLAYER_SIZE
                elif event.key == pyg.K_UP:
                    y -= PLAYER_SIZE
                elif event.key == pyg.K_RIGHT:
                    x += PLAYER_SIZE
                elif event.key == pyg.K_DOWN:
                    y += PLAYER_SIZE
                player_pos = [x, y]

        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        drop_enemies(enemy_list)
        score = update_enemy_pos(enemy_list, score)
        speed = get_speed(score)
        text = 'Your Score is:' + str(score)
        label = game_font.render(text, 1, YELLOW)
        screen.blit(label, (W/2, H-40))
        if collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
            game_over = True
            break
        draw_enemies(enemy_list)
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, RED,
                      (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], PLAYER_SIZE, PLAYER_SIZE))
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pyg.display.update()
#        pyg.display.flip()  # Don't do both update() and flip().


class MenuButton:
    def __init__(self, text, value, rect):
        self.text = text
        self.value = value
        self.rect = rect

    def draw(self):
        # Background color determined by whether mouse is positioned over label.
        mouse_pos = pyg.mouse.get_pos()
        fg_color = RED
        bg_color = BRIGHT_BLUE if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) else BLUE
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, bg_color, self.rect)
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, YELLOW, self.rect, 1)  # Draw a border.

        label = menu_font.render(self.text, 1, fg_color)
        # Center lable text inside its rectangle.
        txw, txh = menu_font.size(self.text)
        screen.blit(label, (self.rect.left + txw/2, self.rect.top + txh/2))


def menu_code():
    MENU_BG_COLOR = (34, 139, 34)
    LABEL_SIZE = LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT = (105, 50)
    B1_RECT = pyg.Rect((W/2 - LABEL_WIDTH/2, H/2 - LABEL_HEIGHT/2), LABEL_SIZE)
    B2_RECT = pyg.Rect((W/2 - LABEL_WIDTH/2, H/2 + LABEL_HEIGHT/2), LABEL_SIZE)
    MENU_BUTTONS = [MenuButton('Start', START, B1_RECT),
                    MenuButton('Quit', QUIT, B2_RECT)]

    choice = None
    while choice is None:
        screen.fill(MENU_BG_COLOR)
        for button in MENU_BUTTONS:
            button.draw()

        for event in pyg.event.get():
            if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
                choice = QUIT
            # Handle left mouse button clicks.
            if event.type == pyg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                for button in MENU_BUTTONS:
                    if button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        choice = button.value
                        break

        pyg.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)

    return choice

# Main loop.
running = True
while running:
    for event in pyg.event.get():
        if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
            running = False
            break;

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    choice = menu_code()
    if choice == START:
        game_code()
    if choice == QUIT:
        running = False
    pyg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.I appreciate the time you put into this.

Comment: Last thing I needed was someone like you to guide  me.

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by that last comment because the phrase "last thing (one) needs" usually [means](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/last+thing+I+want) something which one absolutely does not want or has no use for. Ignoring that…note that I've updated and improved my answer a bit. I'm certainly no pygame expert, but have always been interested in computer graphics and find many applications of it interesting — so it wasn't that much trouble.